# Не получается пробросить порт на виртуальную машину

Tags: linux, macos, virtualbox

Виртуальная машина на VirtualBox

Проброшенные порты (Тип подключения: Nat):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробую подключиться по SSH - всё ок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот с пробросом 8080 не получается. Хотя на серваке все нормально работает.
Если с сервака запрашивать адрес, то:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь пробую с основной машины - вечное ожидание ответа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя порт вроде свободен:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И открыт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В логах доступа (/var/log/nginx/access.log) только запрос от самого сервера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если ради чистоты эксперимента на 8081 например поменять?

Comment: @andreymal Изменил настройку проброса порта с 8080 на 8081 - тоже самое (вечное ожидание ответа): Подключение к localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8081... соединение установлено.
HTTP-запрос отправлен. Ожидание ответа…

Comment: дык `netstat -t4l` посмотри... наверняка nginx только localhost слушает, а не сетевой интерфейс... И все выводы лучше вставлять текстом, а не скринами...

Comment: и если слушает оба, то конфиг nginx'а всё равно посмотри — может он по-разному ведёт себя для разных интерфейсов и/или разных источников запроса; как минимум, проверь что в виртуалке работает `wget "http://<локальный ip-NAT'а>"`

Comment: @Fat-Zer Про скрины принял, спасибо. Вот вывод netstat -t4l: 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:http            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:smtp          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Comment: @Fat-Zer проверил, локальный ip Nat(10.0.2.15) работает. Я тут временно проблему решил другим методом, который почемуто заработал: 

ssh -p 2222 -f -N -L 8081:127.0.0.1:80 root@localhost

Comment: @RosD, гм... не знаю, с виду всё как и должно быть... сейчас на бубунте в дефолтовой конфигурации nginx'а попробовал — всё работает... `Welcome to nginx!` говорит как положено... я бы всё же копал в сторону настройки nginx'а...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Я тоже в какой-то момент просто всё на дефолт устанавливал - не помогло( Может какой файрволл мака чтонибудь блочет, хотя в настройках я его отрубил...

Comment: @RostD, в госте же какая-то шляпа стоит? У меня сейчас нет под рукой чтобы посмотреть, но там дефолтный конфиг может отличаться от бубунтовского... в частности вполне логично по-умолчанию запрещать доступ всем, кто не с локалхоста... так что надо самому смотреть...